# Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$data=$_POST;
    var_dump($data);
//require "PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666; width:100%;" cellpadding="10">';
        $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td style=\"width:150px;\"><strong>Car:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['available_car']) . "</td></tr><br>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Rate:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['rate']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Pickup Address:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['pickup_address']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Time:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['pickup_date']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Full Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['full_name']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone Number:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Comment:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['comment']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "example@multipoint.com";  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "example"; // SMTP password
        $mail->From = "example@multipoint.com";
        $mail->FromName = "name";

        $mail->AddAddress("example@multipoint.com");                  // name is optional

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters

        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
       //$mail->MsgHTML($message); 

        $mail->Body    = "$message";
       if(!$mail->Send())
          {
              echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
              echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
              exit;
           }

           echo "Message has been sent";
    }
   ?>
```

same code is ok on my another server. but its not working on a specific server. it gives a error SMTP `connect()` failed. i watched previous questions with same error but i can't find my solution. 
is it a server issue?? if then what type of issue?? how can i solve it? thanks in advance

Comment: i got the solution . thanks everyone. i just changed the host name from localhost to host name. its working fine now :)

Comment: You could also solve this by installing a local mail server - that's actually a faster approach.